# Protractor: Extracting URL value from an element and using URL to open new browser instance

Tags: protractor

I am trying to do following:

1. get element(div in this case) containing a URL for eg.
   `ele = "www.xyz.com".
2. Use `getAttribute('value')` or `getText()` to
   grep URL
3. Use this URL to fork new instance of browser and GET the
   URL

   newBrowser = browser.forkNewDriverInstance();
    ele.getAttribute('value').then(function(val){
         newBrowser.get(val);
         });

and I am getting following error:
**RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Second method I tried was without promise and got the error saying that url should be string and not object.

As in:

```
var url = ele.getText();
newBrowser.get(url);
```

Is there a way to convert the object returned by `getText()` into a string and store into variable so that it can be used in some other place.

Answer (score 0):

In your second appraoch, `ele.getText()` will give you a promise that needs to be resolved. You can resolve the promise on the second approach by using something like this-

```
ele.getText().then(function(url){
newBrowser.get(url);
})
```

If this does not work, try printing url with `console.log(url)`. I think it is an object array and you need to get the item you need by referring to the index like `url[0]` or `url[1]`. try using console log to print all these values.

Comment: I have not tried your first approach but you should get a handle of the forked browser instance like-   ` `browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
          newWindowHandle = handles[1];
          browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function(){
          <your logic here>  })`

Comment: what is the protractor version you are using?

Comment: Protractor Version 1.6.1

Comment: If that is the case, comment out this portion and do a run. The same error should still come. Confirm it is not an issue with the protractor setup.

Comment: when I have forked new browser instance using "browser.forkNewDriverInstance();". It is an independent instance and i can use it using "newBrowser" handle without switching to it explicitly. I guess even when you do "browser.getAllWindowHandles()" you will get only one instance when you have forked a new instance like newBrowser.

Comment: Hi Aman, please the retry second approach with the edit in my answer